# UseMySql missing option CharSetBehavior(CharSetBehavior.AppendToAllColumns) in .NET 5+

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I used to add the db config in OnConfiguration with code like this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine).EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql("some settings"
            new MariaDbServerVersion(new Version(10, 3, 25)),
            options =>
            {
                options
                .CharSetBehavior(CharSetBehavior.AppendToAllColumns)
                .CharSet(CharSet.Utf8)
                .MigrationsHistoryTable("___EFMigrationsHistory");
            });
    }
```

I think that since the update to .NET 5 this is no longer possible. I get the compiler error:

'MySqlDbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'CharSetBehavior' and no accessible extension method 'CharSetBehavior' accepting a first argument of type 'MySqlDbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found...

Can someone tell me how to achive the same effect as "CharSetBehavior(CharSetBehavior.NeverAppend)" previously had? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can [this question](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1435#issuecomment-846053348) help you? which mentioned `HasCharSet`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `CharSetBehavior` was removed a couple of years ago, you should use the `HasCharSet` instead of it. Please see this comment for more details: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1402#issuecomment-827141383